# associative array in php while selecting data from the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem in fetching associative array

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

this is my code where I face error can any one help me with this one

```
$sqlHoure = "SELECT * from schedule WHERE classname='".$className."'";

$hour = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlHoure);
$h = array();


while ($hour = mysqli_fetch_assoc($hour)){


    $h[$hour['hour']] = $hour['day1'];

   // array_search();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You reassign `$hour` in your loop, I've changed the name of the variable set with the value from `mysqli_query()`...

```
$hourQuery = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlHoure);
$h = array();
while ($hour = mysqli_fetch_assoc($hourQuery)){


    $h[$hour['hour']] = $hour['day1'];

   // array_search();
}
```

You should also look into prepared statements which will save a lot of potential problems in the future.

Comment: yeah i wrote a lot of code my brain stopped working after 5 hours made it hard to see that it's simple xD  ty <3